# Hiding a line while switching between segmented controls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am drawing a line in a UIView using drawRect & BezierPath. I also have a segmented controller with contentview1 and contentview2. I want the line to be displayed in content view1 but not contentview2. The code for my line is in a uiview file while the segmented control is in a uiviewcontroller. How can I successfully hide the line between the 2 content views.

InformationView.m (UIView)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
path.lineWidth = 3;
[[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
[path stroke];

}
```

InformationViewController.m (UIViewController)

```
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(12, 80, 300, 30);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[self.view addSubview:contentView2];
[self.view addSubview:contentView ];

-(void) segmentAction {

if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

    [contentView setHidden:NO;
    [contentView2 setHidden:YES];


}
if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

    [contentView setHidden:YES];
    [contentView2 setHidden: NO];
}
```

I wan't to add the line to contentview so it will be hidden when another view is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to `InformationView`

.h

```
@interface InformationView : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic ,getter=isLineHidden) BOOL lineHidden;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation InformationView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.lineHidden == false) {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
        path.lineWidth = 3;
        [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
        [path stroke];
    }
}

-(void)setLineHidden:(BOOL)lineHidden{
    if (_lineHidden != lineHidden) {
        _lineHidden = lineHidden;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
     }
}

@end
```

Then,when you want to hide line

```
 self.yourView.lineHidden = true;
```